# Right rear caliper failed under warranty. Why do I have to pay for the left side if it's mandatory they be replaced together?

Tags: brake-calipers

As mentioned, the right rear caliper and rotor are being replaced under warranty (KIA 100,000 mile warranty). I understand that the pads are my responsibility, no problem there. I'm told and I do understand that the left rear caliper/rotor needs to be replaced at the same time. Am I responsible for the costs of the left rear rotor if they MUST be replaced together?

Comment: Did they say so? Not clear from your text.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's not *absolutely* mandatory they be  replaced as a pair. It is only *recommended* they be replaced as a pair (at least from my vantage point). If they INSIST they both have to be done, then get them to pay the cost for labor ... just my 2¢ worth.

Comment: Depends on % left vs new of pad thickness.  Do you want to continue changing 1 pad at a time if the kit comes pairs?

Comment: I do understand that both calipers need to go with the pads but it's the left rotor they want to charge me for. It's my view that if the failure of the right causes the replacement of the left, it should all be covered by the warranty while i pay only for the pads, a wear item.